# Typing fast on a list in Python

Tags: list, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

```
my_list = ["Harry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Marry", "Henry"]
```

Each time I've to type quotes, "Name", comma. Is there a way to do it faster? (I'm using Pycharm)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe it's possible to use [live templates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=%5Bpycharm%5D%20live%20template%20) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and looked for an answer and didn´t finda. So the way I´ve found to do this was open only the first and last quotes, then added all strings I wanted only separating with 2 commas (`,,`), after I had put all values in my list, I used the find and replace the 2 commas for quote, comma, quote (`","`). That´s the only way I found to simplify this.

before:

```py
my_list = ["Harry,,Tom,,Jerry,,Marry,,Henry"]
```

after find and replace:

```py
my_list = ["Harry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Marry", "Henry"]
```